# Accessing Visa account history Android

Tags: android

I am working on an app that keeps track of ones spendings. My goal is to integrate tracking of a VISA account into the app. I have looked around but have not found anything in those lines. If someone here knows how I can do it, please share.

Comment: If you are asking if VISA is going to provide you an API to retrieve a card holder's spending history, I can assure you, the answer is no.

Comment: thank you, could there be alternatives?

Comment: I don't have an in depth knowledge of every API out there, but common sense dictates that no one is going to give away their customers' data. It's valuable, and what's in it for them? They want to drive people to their own apps and website for that information.

Comment: Alternative some banks offer API for developers, then you can fetch visa card history, as far as I know in my country the access to API is not free of charge.

Comment: thank you everyone